# Getting specific id in each loop

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to build a pool system for world cup predictions. 
In here I've got games, with team's. I want to list them and give them fields for predictions. I've got those working, only separate. Now I want to combine them.

In my predictions new view there's this code:

```
<%= form_tag controller: :predictions, action: :create_multiple_predictions do %>
  <% @predictions.each_with_index do |prediction, index| %>
    <%= fields_for "predictions[#{index}]", prediction do |p| %>
      <% @pool.each do |pool| %>
      <%= p.hidden_field :poolmembership_id, :value => Poolmembership.find_by_user_id_and_pool_id(current_user.id, pool.id).id %>
      <% end %> 

      <%= p.label :prediction1, 'prediction 1' %>
      <%= p.number_field :prediction1 %>
      <%= p.label :prediction2, 'prediction 2' %>
      <%= p.number_field :prediction2 %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Sign In' %>
<% end %>
```

I can list all my games with this:

```
<% @game.each do |game| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= Team.find(game.team1_id).name %></td>
    <td>                  
      <% if game.score1 == nil && game.score2 == nil %>
        x - x
      <% else %>
        <%= game.score1 %> - <%= game.score2 %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

The problem now is where to place the game_id hidden field.

```
<% @game.each do |game| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :game_id, :value => game.id %>
<% end %>
```

I don't need the other parts of the game information. Only the game.id should be submitted with the form. When i place it inside of the predictions.each loop it works, but then it will pick the last game id in the table, which is logical. ( If you place the game loop in the prediction loop, the game loop will stop at the end of his loop, which will put the last id of games. I will edit the question. )

What i need is a way to combine the game information, with the prediction fields, and at the end one submit button for all the different prediction fields.

For help, here's my prediction controller and some model information. (The new(2) should be the count of games or something, this was just for trying to get it work, each game should have one prediction1 and one prediction2 field.)

```
def new  
  @pool = Pool.all
  @game = Game.all
  @predictions = Array.new(2) { Prediction.new }
end

def create
  @predictions = Prediction.new(prediction_params)
  if @prediction.save
    redirect_to predictions_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def create_multiple_predictions
  params[:predictions].each do |k,v|
  prediction = Prediction.new
  prediction.prediction1 = v['prediction1']
  prediction.prediction2 = v['prediction2']
  prediction.poolmembership_id = v['poolmembership_id']
  prediction.save      
end
```

The relations between the models:

```
class Pool < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :poolmemberships
  has_many :users, through: :pool memberships

class Poolmembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pool
  belongs_to :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: [:pool_id]
  has_many :predictions

class Prediction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  has_one :poolmembership
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
  has_many :predictions, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Comment: At first thought I want to bring up Form Objects as discussed in this blog post: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/ or this Rails Cast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects - but these are a bit more involved than a simple solution you likely need for this one specific problem.  I may be a bit off this morning, but could you clean up your question a little bit - it may help make things 'click' and others will be able to give you an answer more quickly.  This seems like a very simple problem, just need some clarification.

Comment: What are the relationships between Pool, Game and Prediction? And Poolmembership?

Comment: . . . continuing my thought (comment character count limit): "When i place it inside of the predictions.each loop it works, but then it will pick the last game id in the table, which is logical."  - I think that's the spot where we need the most clarification.

Comment: @Ecnalyr If you place the game loop in the prediction loop, the game loop will stop at the end of his loop, which will put the last id of games. I will edit the question.

Comment: @Mischa I will add them to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over all the games and create predictions for them. I think you only have to define `@games` like this.

```
def new
  @games = Game.all
end
```

In your form you have to make sure that the keys in `predictions` hash that gets submitted to the controller are unique. This can be done like this:

```
<%= form_tag controller: :predictions, action: :create_multiple_predictions do %>
  <% @games.each do |game| %>
    <%= fields_for "predictions[#{game.id}]", Prediction.new do |p| %>
      <%= p.label :prediction1, 'prediction 1' %>
      <%= p.number_field :prediction1 %>
      <%= p.label :prediction2, 'prediction 2' %>
      <%= p.number_field :prediction2 %>
      <%= p.hidden_field :game_id, :value => game.id %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

By the way, the relationship between `Prediction` and `Poolmembership` is wrong. It should be:

```
Prediction belongs_to :poolmembership
```

not:

```
Prediction has_one :pool membership
```

I don't understand what you're trying to do here:

```
<% @pool.each do |pool| %>
  <%= p.hidden_field :poolmembership_id, :value => Poolmembership.find_by_user_id_and_pool_id(current_user.id, pool.id).id %>
<% end %>
```

This can't be right. You should show a drop down or something where the user can select in which pool he wants to submit the prediction. Now it's always submitted to the last pool.

Comment: When I use your code, only the last prediction is saved as I can see in my terminal. Also the game id isn't there. Do I need to add more code, because you say that I don't need the hidden field. The part you don't understand is for finding the pool membership, this is the connection between an user and a pool where he's playing. And yes you're right, at the moment it doesn't find the right pool, just picks the last one, sort of the same problem. Only, the pool id is in the url, so I guess I will find my solution there. Instead of dropdown pool page where the user came from.

Comment: @LiveNL, I updated my answer. Does this work? I don't understand why only the last one is saved. In your version both predictions are saved?

Comment: same story, your version in terminal:  "predictions"=>{"0"=>{"prediction1"=>"1", "prediction2"=>"1", "game_id"=>"3"}}, "commit"=>"Save changes"}. Mine: "predictions"=>{"0"=>{"poolmembership_id"=>"4", "prediction1"=>"1", "prediction2"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"poolmembership_id"=>"4", "prediction1"=>"3", "prediction2"=>"4"}}, "commit"=>"Sign In"} (This has two predictions as decided in the controller, and no game_id). And in rails console the amount of records isn't updated with more than 1 in your version, so i'm pretty sure.

Comment: Well, at least the `game_id` is there ;-) What does the generated html of the form look like?

Comment: Part of my version: <input id="predictions_0_poolmembership_id" name="predictions[0][poolmembership_id]" type="hidden" value="4" />



                      <label for="predictions_0_prediction1">prediction 1</label>
                      <input id="predictions_0_prediction1" name="predictions[0][prediction1]" type="number" /> .

Comment: Your version        <label for="predictions_0_prediction1">prediction 1</label>
        <input id="predictions_0_prediction1" name="predictions[0][prediction1]" type="number" />
        <label for="predictions_0_prediction2">prediction 2</label>
        <input id="predictions_0_prediction2" name="predictions[0][prediction2]" type="number" />
        <input id="predictions_0_game_id" name="predictions[0][game_id]" type="hidden" value="1" />

Comment: Both have `predictions[0][prediction1]`, so that's looks OK. Is there also `predictions[1][prediction1]` in my version? And in yours?

Comment: Is your site available online somewhere, so I can have a look?

Comment: Yes and yes, we both have them. No the prediction part isn't online yet. The rest of it (pools, users, poolmemberships) is already in the www.dev.mijnwkpool.com version. But I don't think that helps that much.

Comment: Can you create a [public gist](https://gist.github.com) of the html of both versions?

Comment: Yours: https://gist.github.com/LiveNL/e3f1f2f8892d188c24fa Mine: https://gist.github.com/LiveNL/e552945f50c730193b2d

Comment: I edited my answer again. The problem with my previous answer was that the key in the `predictions` hash was not unique. This should fix that. Just to be sure: you want to submit two predictions per game, right?

Comment: They're getting saved now! Only without game id's, but those are in the params, so I guess we're almost there. One game has one prediction record, which has prediction1 and prediction2, 1 and 2 stand for score of home team and score of away team. I guess changing 2 times to 1 is the right thing to do first.

Comment: `2.times` can be removed altogether then. See edit. As for the not saving, did you add `prediction.game_id = v['game_id']` to `create_multiple_predictions`?

Comment: Many many thanks! It work's amazing. I will try to fix the pool memberships now. Thanks again (can't give you +1 :( )